# GIT how to split up commits from branch into different branches?

Tags: git

I have a single branch with commits for feature A, B, C, D. I have about 40 commits, and each of the commits are in mixed order.
I have made a pull request, but I need to split up this branch into branch A, branch B, etc. with the commits associated with each feature. So feature A commits in branch A.

Unfortunately, i'm new to git and it still confuses me. How do you pull out the commits from a single branch and put them inside their own branch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `git cherry-pick`
Create new branch for feature A, checkout on it and use: `git cherry-pick a_commit_hash`.
Repeat it for all your commits

Answer (score 1):

Try using this syntax:

```
git checkout -b A_branch <SHA-1 hash for commit A>
git push origin A_branch
```

The first command creates a new branch called `A_branch` based on the A commit.  It also checks out that branch.  Then, we push your new branch to the remote.  Just repeat the above two commands for each of the four commits and you are done.

Note: To find out the SHA-1 hash for each of the four commits, you may run `git log` from the HEAD of your current branch.  SHA-1 hashes look something like this:

```
3dk92dk2lvnkls ...
```

This is the commit hash for some commit.

**Edit:**

Note that these operations do not affect your original branch.  After you have created and pushed everything you need, you may return to your original branch via:

```
git checkout original_branch
```

Comment: Made an edit: I have about 40 commits, and each of the commits are in mixed order, so could be commit for A B B A D C etc. - if I checkout to the new branch at specific commit. How can i access commits 'of the future' ?

Comment: You don't, to answer your access question.  With regard to your comment about the commits being mixed, I have no idea what you are talking about.

Comment: I mean, let's say you have an order of 1 to 40. 40 is current time, 1 is the beginning of time. If i go to number 3, do I still have access to the 37 commits of the future? I currently understood it as git checkout -b branch sha-1 hash goes to specific commit and point in timeline.

Comment: @J.Reku If I understand you correctly, you are worried about these operations affecting your original branch.  They won't, see my update.

Comment: I'm worried that this will just checkout to a specific commit and I won't be able to put the 12+- other commits of feature A inside this branch.